# android numberpicker for floating point numbers

Tags: android, spinner, numberpicker

The user of our app should be able to adjust a floating point number. At the moment, I filled an ArrayAdapter with all possible values and attached it to a spinner.

This solution doesn't really meet our expectations, since the spinner dropdown box is way too tall. Is there a better way? I was looking at Numberpicker - but this seems to work only with Integer values.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me suggest another solution [DecimalPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047964/753575)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`NumberPicker` is not just for integers.. Even you can use `Floats` `String` etc.

see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) and read about it.

for tutorials :

- http://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/android-number-picker-dialog/

And I had used `NumberPicker` long ago like this and it might be some use posting here:

```
    NumberPicker np;
    String nums[]= {"Select Fraction","1/64","1/32","3/64","1/16","5/64","3/32","7/64","1/8","9/64","5/32","11/64","3/16","13/64","7/32","15/64","1/4","17/64","9/32","19/64","5/16","21/64","11/32","23/64","3/8","25/64","13/32","27/64","7/16","29/64"};

            np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);

            np.setMaxValue(nums.length-1);
            np.setMinValue(0);
            np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
            np.setDisplayedValues(nums);
            np.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

You can make `ArrayList` of any datatype and assign it.

Comment: Your solution is great! Thank you, but I have one question: how can I set value programmaticaly, when I have `String nums[]`?

Comment: If you are going to go down this route, using a Formatter would be a better way as per my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464571/getting-float-double-from-numberpicker/18501759#comment85086496_18501759

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to **combine two numberfields** into one component. See the [Money Picker Example](http://pestohacks.blogspot.ru/2015/04/number-money-picker-dialog-in-android.html). Its advantage is that you don't have to initialize all possible double values for your spinner.

You may also need to attach **special digits formatting**, like *"00"*, *"0123"* or other, using `java.lang.String.format()` function. Example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030765/1112963).

1. Add Double Picker xml-layout:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:gravity = "center">

     <NumberPicker
       android:id = "@+id/integer_picker"
       android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity = "center"/>

     <TextView
       android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity = "center"
       android:padding = "5dp"
       android:text = "@string/local_separator"
       android:textSize = "20sp"/>

     <NumberPicker
       android:id = "@+id/fraction_picker"
       android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity = "center"/>

     <TextView
       android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity = "center"
       android:padding = "5dp"
       android:text = "@string/measure_unit_sign"
       android:textSize = "20sp"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Add custom Double Picker class:

   ```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.widget.NumberPicker;

   /**
    * UI component for double (floating point) values. Can be used
    * for money and other measures.
    */
   public class DoublePicker
     extends NumberPicker {

     private int decimals;
     private NumberPicker integerPicker;
     private NumberPicker fractionPicker;

     public DoublePicker(
       Context context) {

       super(
         context);

         LayoutInflater
           .from(
             context)
           .inflate(
             R.layout.double_picker,
             this);

         integerPicker =
           (NumberPicker) findViewById(
             R.id.integer_picker);

         fractionPicker =
           (NumberPicker) findViewById(
             R.id.fraction_picker);
     }

     public int getDecimals() {

       return decimals;
     }

     /**
      * Sets the amount of digits after separator.
      *
      * @param decimals Anount of decimals.
      */
     public void setDecimals(final int decimals) {

       this.decimals = decimals;

       this.setFormatter(new DoublePicker.Formatter() {

         @Override
         public String format(int i) {

           return String.format(
             "%." + decimals + "f",
             i);
         }
       });
     }

     public void setValue(double value) {

       integerPicker.setValue((int) value);

       fractionPicker.setValue(
         Integer.valueOf(
           String
             .valueOf(value)
             .split(".")
             [1]));
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use new Double Picker component in your activity xml:

   ```
   <com.example.DoublePicker
     android:id ="@+id/double_picker"
     android:layout_width ="match_parent"
     android:layout_height ="wrap_content" />
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin**, you can use this handy `NumberPicker` extension dialog which scales your `Double` values into a fitting `Int` range and converts the `Int` values back to `Double`s before calling any of the callback. So it basicallly hides away the fact that `NumberPicker` only supports `Int`. It just feels like `NumberPicker` would actually support `Double`, try it out!

Here's the **Fragment extension** you need to **copy & paste**:

```
fun Fragment.showNumberPickerDialog(
    title: String,
    value: Double,
    range: ClosedRange<Double>,
    stepSize: Double,
    formatToString: (Double) -> String,
    valueChooseAction: (Double) -> Unit
) {
    val numberPicker = NumberPicker(context).apply {
        setFormatter { formatToString(it.toDouble() * stepSize) }
        wrapSelectorWheel = false

        minValue = (range.start / stepSize).toInt()
        maxValue = (range.endInclusive / stepSize).toInt()
        this.value = (value.toDouble() / stepSize).toInt()

        // NOTE: workaround for a bug that rendered the selected value wrong until user scrolled, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27343772/3451975
        (NumberPicker::class.java.getDeclaredField("mInputText").apply { isAccessible = true }.get(this) as EditText).filters = emptyArray()
    }

    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setView(numberPicker)
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ -> valueChooseAction(numberPicker.value.toDouble() * stepSize) }
        .setNeutralButton("Cancel") { _, _ -> /* do nothing, closes dialog automatically */ }
        .show()
}
```

Now you can **use it** like this (in a `Fragment`):

```
showNumberPickerDialog(
    title = "Your Weight",
    value = 75.0, // in kilograms
    range = 10.0 .. 300.0,
    stepSize = 0.1,
    formatToString = { "$it kg" },
    valueChooseAction = { saveNewWeight(it) }
)
```

Comment: works well, Theme needs to derive from Theme.MaterialComponents.some_theme cant derive from AppCompat