# Getting float/double from NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am trying the https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker library and the reference is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#getValue%28%29
Now both, the API level 11 NumberPicker returns int value in getValue method and also the SimonVT numberpicker returns int value.

But I had set double values in the number picker by using following code:

```
String[] nums = {"1","1.5","2","2.5","3","3.5","4","4.5","5","5.5","6","6.5","7","7.5","8","8.5","9"};

final NumberPicker listeningScorenp = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.listeningScore);
listeningScorenp.setMaxValue(nums.length-1);
listeningScorenp.setMinValue(0);
listeningScorenp.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
listeningScorenp.setDisplayedValues(nums);
```

Now I am stuck with how to retrieve the float/double values from NUmberPicker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tested using your code. getValue() actually returns the index of the item selected (only when you set the displayed values). All you'll need to do is parse the string and you will have what you wanted.

```
String[] nums = {"1","1.5","2","2.5","3","3.5","4","4.5","5","5.5","6","6.5","7","7.5","8","8.5","9"};
int index = listeningScorenp.getValue();
String val = nums[index];
float selectedFloat = Float.parseFloat(val);
```

Comment: Also you have the option of using NumberPicker.Formatter https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.Formatter.html if for example you wanted to format the float as fractions in your strings

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin**, you can use this handy `NumberPicker` extension which presents a dialog – under the wraps it scales your `Double` values into a fitting `Int` range and converts the `Int` values back to `Double`s before calling any of the callback. So it basicallly hides away the fact that `NumberPicker` only supports `Int`. It just feels like `NumberPicker` would actually support `Double`, try it out!

Here's the **Fragment extension** you can to **copy & paste**:

```
fun Fragment.showNumberPickerDialog(
    title: String,
    value: Double,
    range: ClosedRange<Double>,
    stepSize: Double,
    formatToString: (Double) -> String,
    valueChooseAction: (Double) -> Unit
) {
    val numberPicker = NumberPicker(context).apply {
        setFormatter { formatToString(it.toDouble() * stepSize) }
        wrapSelectorWheel = false

        minValue = (range.start / stepSize).toInt()
        maxValue = (range.endInclusive / stepSize).toInt()
        this.value = (value.toDouble() / stepSize).toInt()

        // NOTE: workaround for a bug that rendered the selected value wrong until user scrolled, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27343772/3451975
        (NumberPicker::class.java.getDeclaredField("mInputText").apply { isAccessible = true }.get(this) as EditText).filters = emptyArray()
    }

    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setView(numberPicker)
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ -> valueChooseAction(numberPicker.value.toDouble() * stepSize) }
        .setNeutralButton("Cancel") { _, _ -> /* do nothing, closes dialog automatically */ }
        .show()
}
```

Then you can **use it** like this:

```
showNumberPickerDialog(
    title = "Your Weight",
    value = 75.0, // in kilograms
    range = 10.0 .. 300.0,
    formatToString = { "$it kg" },
    valueChooseAction = { saveNewWeight(it) }
)
```