# Android Numberpicker default value not coming

Tags: android, numberpicker

When the numberpicker is loaded, the default value is not appearing on the screen until touched.

Once touched, everything works fine.Any help appreciated.

Also if the formatter is removed, it works fine.

[image]

dialog.xml

```
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/apply_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/number_picker"
    android:text="@string/ok_string" />
```

Here is the activity code:

```
final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
        np.setMaxValue(50);
        np.setMinValue(0);
        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
        np.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

        np.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
            @Override
            public String format(int i) {
                if (i == 25)
                    return "0";
                else
                    return String.valueOf(i - 25);
            }
        });
        np.setValue(25);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be that the initial text color matches the background color? Hard to visualize what you are seeing without a device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NumberPicker with Formatter does not format on first rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708325/android-numberpicker-with-formatter-does-not-format-on-first-rendering)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to a bug in NumberPicker widget.

And I have solved it using method 2 described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35482).

Answer (score 7):

@Renjith

Thank for the link, but I think you should link the code or even paste it here.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35482#c9

```
Field f = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mInputText");
f.setAccessible(true);
EditText inputText = f.get(mPicker);
inputText.setFilters(new InputFilter[0]);
```

Comment: Kotlin version below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59704146/3451975

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for this bug in NumberPicker that works in APIs 18-26 without using reflection and without using `setDisplayedValues()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44949069/3918479).

Answer (score 3):

Here's the accepted answer written in **Kotlin** in a single line:

```
// NOTE: workaround for a bug that rendered the selected value wrong until user scrolled, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27343772/3451975
(NumberPicker::class.java.getDeclaredField("mInputText").apply { isAccessible = true }.get(this) as EditText).filters = emptyArray()
```

Note that I recommend to keep the comment line to document *why* this code is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was using `NumberPicker` with Strings.
My problem was that after the activity was opened with a transition the the default value in the number picker was invisible, even though i was setting the picker values with `picker.setDisplayedValues(list.toStringsArray())`

[image]

So for me the solution was the following:

```
private void populatePicker(NumberPicker picker, String[] strings, int index) {
    picker.setDisplayedValues(null);
    picker.setMinValue(0);
    picker.setMaxValue(strings.length - 1);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(strings);
    picker.setValue(index);

    try {
        Field field = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mInputText");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        EditText inputText = (EditText) field.get(picker);
        inputText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

Comment: Can you expand on why this is perhaps better than the accepted answer?