# How do you display a 2 digit NumberPicker in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, numberpicker

I want to create a timer and since I couldn't create a digital interface that is editable for the user to set the time I want to use the NumberPicker.  However the NumberPicker only displays 1 digit for the numbers between 0-9.  How do you format the picker so that it will display two digits such as 01 02 03 and so forth.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(10);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(int i) {
            return String.format("%02d", i);
        }
    });
```

This will do the trick!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Implement a custom [NumberPicker.Formatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.Formatter.html) that implements your value display padding and call [setFormatter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setFormatter%28android.widget.NumberPicker.Formatter%29).

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. `public class MyTwoDigitFormatter implements Formatter {
 public String format(int value)
 {
  return String.format("%02d", value);
 }
}`

Answer (score 4):

```
 NumberPicker monthPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.np_month);
        monthPicker.setMinValue(1);
        monthPicker.setMaxValue(12);
        monthPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
            @Override
            public String format(int i) {
                return String.format("%02d", i);
            }
        });
```