# Double (decimal) Number Picker for daily weight tracking - Android

Tags: android, decimal, numberpicker

I've been researching this for hours with no progress.
I need an easy user interface to enter daily weight.
I'm trying to avoid an `EditText` interface for it lacking in the user experience.
My FitnessPal, for example, has exactly what I am looking for.
[MyFitnessPal's weight input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyGES.png)
The Android number picked seems hard wired for integers. If it allows for double variables, I can't figure out how to make it work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645927/android-numberpicker-for-floating-point-numbers

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this question/answer.  It doesn't address my question.  Firstly I can't pre program every number from 80.0 lbs to 350.5 lbs and enter to an array.  The links aren't much help either.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using two separate number pickers (integer), aligning them side by side, and placing a TextView "period" between them -- to give the appearance of a double variable.  Then in the java, I converted them to doubles, performed some math and was able to get my number.  Maybe not the most efficient, but it worked.